# when $R[u]\cong R[x]/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

In "Basic Algebra" Chapter 2.10, page 122, Jacobson gives the following theorem:

> **THEOREM**. Let $R$ and $S$ be (commutative) rings, $\mu$  a homomorphism of $R$ into $S$, $u$ an element of $S$. Let $R[x]$ be the ring of polynomials over $R$ in the indeterminate $x$. Then $\mu$ has one and only one extension to a homomorphism $\mu_u$ of $R[x]$ into $S$ mapping $x$ into $u$.

and then in page 123,  the following corollary:

> **COROLLARY**. $R[u]\cong R[x]/I$ where $x$ is indeterminate and I is an ideal in $R[x]$ such that $I\cap R=0$.

Is not there supposed to be some sort of a condition on $u$? Is it true to all $u$? If, for example, the ideal $I$ is principle, then we always get an isomorphism. It seems to me a little strange. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is $u$ here? Another indeterminate?

Comment: $u$ is an element of a ring extension of $R$.

Comment: Yes. I reedit  my question.

Comment: It would be helpful to give the preceding theorem, which specifies the data.  It is common for corollaries to reuse parts of the statement of the theorem.

Comment: ok. i wrote the theorem preceding this corollary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paragraph leading up to the corollary says what $u$ and $I$ are: $u$ is an arbitrary element in a ring extension $S$ of $R$ that is not in $R$, and $I$ is the kernel of the map $R[x]\to S$ defined by $x\mapsto u$.  The point is that if there is a ring extension $R[u]$, then there is some ideal $I$ such that $R[u]$ is isomorphic to $R[x]/I$, where the ideal has the property that $R\cap I=0$.  I do not believe it is saying anything about the converse, that rings of the form $R[x]/I$ with $I\cap R=0$ are ring extensions by a single element.

---

Stylistically, this is one of those books where you have to read all the text between the theorems and proofs because it contains important descriptions of variables.

Comment: I see, but is page 124 (just after this corollary) he wrote: "Conversely, if $I$ is an ideal in $R[x]$ such that $I\cap R=0$, then..." ending with "Hence $R[x]/I\cong R[u]$"

Comment: Yes, that is weird.  Perhaps clearing up the argument: the evaluation map $R[x]\to S$ has a kernel $I$, and by the first isomorphism theorem, it follows that $R[x]/I$ is isomorphic to the subring of $S$ generated by $R$ and $u$ (i.e., the image of $R[x]\to S$).  Of course, there is an inclusion map $R\to R[x]$, and Jacobson checks that the composition $R\to R[x]\to S$ is injective.  Since the map is an evaluation map, $I\cap R=0$, and Jacobson uses this fact to conclude the map is injective, and thus that you can pretend $R$ is literally a subring of $R[x]/I$.

Comment: (I'm not convinced Jacobson is using "conversely" accurately.  I think it's to point out how the corollary is sort of a converse to the theorem.  The theorem was about extending a homomorphism to a ring of polynomials, and the corollary is about images of homomorphisms of ring polynomial maps.)